# PDO INSERT INTO is not working

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out what is wrong with my query, and was not able to figure out. I have search the internet and S.O found few similar answers but none seems to work.

pLease see the attacked code and help me figure our what the problem is.

```
  public function add_page($page=array()){
global $db;

//define page properties
$page_name = $page['page_name'];
$page_title= $page['page_title'];
$page_meta_description = $page['page_meta_description'];
$page_meta_keywords = $page['page_meta_keywords'];
$page_meta_other = $page['page_meta_other'];
$page_meta_other_2= $page['page_meta_other_2'];
$page_url = $page['page_url'];
$page_summary = $page['page_summary'];
$page_content = $page['page_content'];
$page_nav_item = $page['page_nav_item']; 
$page_nav_name= $page['page_nav_name'];


    $q="INSERT INTO `simplecms`.`pages` (`page_id`, `page_name`, `page_title`, `page_meta_description`, `page_meta_keywords`, `page_meta_other`, `page_other_2`, `page_url`, `page_summary`, `page_content`, `page_nav_item`, `page_nav_name`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);

    $query->bindValue(1,$page_name);
    $query->bindValue(2,$page_title);
    $query->bindValue(3,$page_meta_description);
    $query->bindValue(4,$page_meta_keywords );
    $query->bindValue(5,$page_meta_other);
    $query->bindValue(6,$page_meta_other_2);
    $query->bindValue(7,$page_url );
    $query->bindValue(8,$page_summary);
    $query->bindValue(9,$page_content );
    $query->bindValue(10,$page_nav_item);
    $query->bindValue(11,$page_nav_name);

    $query->execute();
    $r=$query->rowCount();

    echo $r;



    //VALUES (NULL, 'Page Name', 'Page Title', 'Meta  page description', 'google, ooogle ogle, userher', 'dymmy text qq', '', 'google.com', 'Small Summary', 'Ths is the big text', 'Yes', 'Google.com');


    /*
    $query= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `pages`(`page_name`, `page_title`, `page_meta_description`, `page_meta_keywords`, `page_meta_other`, `page_other_2`, `page_url`, `page_summary`, `page_content`, `page_nav_item`, `page_nav_name`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $query->execute(array(
        $page_name,
        $page_title,
        $page_meta_description,
        $page_meta_keywords,
        $page_meta_other,
        $page_meta_other_2,
        $page_url,
        $page_summary,
        $page_content,
        $page_nav_item,
        $page_nav_name
        ));
    $query->execute();

    $row = $query->rowCount();
    echo $row;*/

    /*
    $query = "INSERT INTO `pages`(
                    `page_name`,
                    `page_title`,
                    `page_meta_description`,
                    `page_meta_keywords`,
                    `page_meta_other`,
                    `page_meta_other_2`,
                    `page_url`,
                    `page_summary`,
                    `page_content`,
                    `page_nav_item`,
                    `page_nav_name`
                    )  VALUES(
                    :name,
                    :title,
                    :desctription,
                    :keywords,
                    :meta1,
                    :meta2,
                    :url,
                    :summary,
                    :content,
                    :navitem,
                    :navname

                    )";
                                            //VALUE(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $q = $db->prepare($query);
    $q->execute(array(
                    ':name'                 =>$page_name,
                    ':title'                =>$page_title,
                    ':desctription'         =>$page_meta_description,
                    ':keywords'             =>$page_meta_keywords,
                    ':meta1'                =>$page_meta_other,
                    ':meta2'                =>$page_meta_other_2,
                    ':url'                  =>$page_url,
                    ':summary'              =>$page_summary,
                    ':content'              =>$page_content,
                    ':navitem'              =>$page_nav_item,
                    ':navname'              =>$page_nav_name
        ));
        */
    /*$q->bindValue(':name', $page_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':title', $page_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':desctription', $page_meta_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':keywords', $page_meta_keywords, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':meta1', $page_meta_other, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':meta2', $page_meta_other_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':url', $page_url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':summary', $page_summary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':content', $page_content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':navitem', $page_nav_item, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindValue(':navname', $page_nav_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();*/

    /*$r = $q->rowCount();

    if($r<1){
        echo "Oops no article is added <pre>";
        print_r($page);
        echo "</pre>";
    }else{

        echo $r."Google";
    }
    */
```

}

I have tried pretty much any/ all methods i could think off. I have browsed the internet for hours and is not working,

In the same class, i am able to select and fetch all data from the database, but inserting into the database has became a nightmare.

Please help.

Comment: whats the error your having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page_id` is missing from the `VALUES`. You have 12 fields, but 11 placeholders and 11 `bindValue`.

If `page_id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, don't include it in the field list.

Comment: Nice catch on the page_id, that i just added to see if that would fix the issue but it did not and i removed it, i just forgot to remove from the column's. As you can see if my other codes, i tried many different ways, it just does not insert. I have a users class, code is almost identical but users class Insert works but Pages class insert would not work regardless of what i do.

Comment: Insert `print_r($query->errorInfo());` right after `$query->execute()`, to see what MySQL complains about.

Comment: Thank you much, found what the issue was, i had the page_url field as a unique field while the data i was entering had no data  in page_url causing duplicate entry error.                                                     Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1062 [2] => Duplicate entry 'this is a unique field' for key 'page_url' ) 0